# Add mean values of different periods of a time series in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, time-series, mean

I am analyzing a time series and I would like to show in ggplot the mean values and the confidence intervals calculated on different time series periods, like in the attached graph. How can I do that?
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a first step add a column to your dataset for the periods for which you want to add the means and confidence intervals. In a second step create a dataset containing the start and end date of your periods as well as the mean and the values used for the confidence interval. In the code below I use `ggplot2::mean_sdl` to compute the three stats. Reshape the aggregated data to long and finally use a `geom_segment` to draw the lines for the three stats by period

Using a minimal reproducible example based on `ggplot2::economics`:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)
library(lubridate, warn.conflicts = FALSE)

economics2 <- economics[c("date", "psavert")]

economics2 <- economics2 |>
  mutate(
    period = case_when(
      year(date) <= 1985 ~ 1,
      year(date) <= 2000 ~ 2,
      .default = 3
    )
  )

economics2_agg <- economics2 |>
  summarise(
    start = min(date),
    end = max(date),
    mean_sdl(psavert),
    .by = period
  ) |>
  tidyr::pivot_longer(c(y, ymin, ymax), names_to = "stat")

ggplot(economics2, aes(date, psavert)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_segment(
    data = economics2_agg,
    aes(
      x = start, xend = end,
      y = value, yend = value,
      linetype = stat,
      color = factor(period)
    )
  ) +
  scale_linetype_manual(
    values = c(y = "solid", ymin = "dashed", ymax = "dashed")
  )
```

[image]